# flex modular application resources

Tags: apache-flex

I'd like to know what are the best practices when creanting a complex and big flex modular application? particularly concercing internationalization, performance, remoting(service), skinning, caching, logging.

How to use theses common resources?

Imagine that many developers will work on the same project, but on different 'small' modules each, and they don't have to know how the entire application works. So every developer will create and compile his/her module (swf), and I'll just have to put these swf in their appropriate folders.

What do you think about this approach:

1. create a common library : myAppLibrary, which manage languages, services, caching, logging, debuging.. For example this library can have these functions : `translate(str:String):String`, `callAmfService(class:String,methode:string,...params)`, `loadCache(cacheKey:String):Object`, etc
2. require that every module(developer) should use this library when handling languages, services etc. Eg within a module, a developper can do : langSingleton::getInstance()->translate('somestring') for example
3. make modules communicate by events

(sorry if my english's not clear)

Thanks

Comment: I voted to close; please read the FAQ for types of questions this site targets: http://stackoverflow.com/faq .  I feel this constitutes a "Chatty open ended question."  Generally anything that relates to 'best practices' is by it's nature subjective.

Comment: Is there a better place to ask these kind of questions, maybe `Programmers`? Personally, I wouldn't mind a little input regarding this topic as well.